# Edit discord message from webhook

Tags: discord, protocols

I want to send a message with a webhook (which I have working), then edit that message. You can edit messages through webhooks, but you need the message id. The only way to retrieve a message through webhooks requires the message id. How is this system supposed to work? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the `wait` Query String Parameter to `true` otherwise discord will only reply with a 204 No Content. All the Query String Parameters are listed in the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook).

So basically just add a "?wait=true" to your discord webhook url and you should get a response with the message id (and more). Then you can use that id to Lookup/Edit/Delete that message.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have accepted earlier, but I only just recovered my stack exchange account.